# How can I make this bash script into an one-liner?

Tags: bash

I need a more compact, preferably an one-liner, for the following bash script:

```
#/bin/sh
service openstack-keystone status > /dev/null
service_rc=$?
keystone token-get 2>&1 | grep "^Authentication Failed" > /dev/null
keystone_rc=$?
if [ $service_rc != 0 -o $keystone_rc == 0 ]
then
        echo "need to restart"
else
        echo "ok"
fi
```

I eventually have to get this logic into a puppet service where the standard status check is not enough.

Updated. Sorry for not be more clear in my initial question and thanks to you that have commented and answered. :)

Comment: What benefit do you expect from compressing it to one line? Testing `[-e file ]` is a much better way to test whether a file exists than parsing the error output of `ls`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
service blah status > /dev/null &&
    keystone token-get 2>&1 | grep -q "^Authentication Failed" &&
    echo "ok" || echo "need to restart"
```

Comment: thanks for you excellent answer.  But I should probably update my question because I was just using `ls ...` to simulate output to stderr.  I actually will be executing the command `keystone token-get` and grepping for the string "Authentication Failed" in stderr.